# Probability Between Two Normally Distributed Variables

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

> The weight of medium-size tomatoes selected at random from a bin at the local supermarket is a normal random variable with mean $μ = 10$ ounces and standard deviation $σ = 1$ ounce. Suppose we pick two tomatoes at random from the bin, so the weights of the tomatoes are independent.
>
> What is the probability the difference in the weights of the two tomatoes exceeds 2 ounces?

I understand that $μ(x-y) = μx - μy$, and therefore $μ = 0$ ounces.

I also understand that the standard deviation should be $\sqrt{σx^2 + σy^2}$.

Where should I go from here?

(Note: I have a TI-84 Plus calculator and am attempting to use the normalcdf function to no avail.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean to say is that the mean of the distribution should be $\mu_1$ - $\mu_2$, and the standard deviation of the distribution should be $\sqrt{\sigma^2_1 + \sigma^2_2}$. I do not know where you have $x$ and $y$.

Now, given that the mean is $0$, and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{2}$, how many standard deviations of this distribution is $2$ oz?